# Passing string argument to jQuery and it thinks its function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following funciton

```
function showPossibleLocationToAdd() {
    var ulist = $("<ul data-rok='listview' id='addLocationList'></ul>").appendTo("#addLocation");
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        console.log("calling" + i*5 + "," + i*3 + ",Location " + i);
        var name = "Location " ;
        $("<li><a href='#settingsPage' data-role='button' onclick='addNewLoc("+ i*5 + "," + i*3 + "," + name +  ")'>Location " + i + "</a></li>").appendTo("#addLocationList");
    }
}
```

which should dynamically create a list with on click event that should call this function :

```
function addNewLoc(long, lat, name) {
    console.log(long);
    console.log(lat);
    console.log(name);
}
```

but the outputs after clicking on link I get this reposonse for example :

25
15
function Location() { [native code]}

So my question is why it thinks variable name is a function and not String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are passing `Location` to your function. Which is a native constructor in some browsers. It's not a string in your code. You should avoid using `onclick` attributes. You can store the value in a `data-*` attribute, delegate the events for dynamically generated elements using jQuery, and then read the `data-*` attribute in your event handler using the `.data()` method, like: `$(this).data('location')`.

Answer (score 0):

addNewLoc is binded on the click event ? This is a normal purpose.

When binding event, the first argument is always the event.

Try this :

```
function addNewLoc(e, long, lat, name) {
    console.log(long);
    console.log(lat);
    console.log(name);
}
```